# Passing multiple paramaters to forTypesAndDirections function in Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm trying to pass a variable number of paired arguments to function [forTypesAndDirection](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/PathExpanders.html#forTypesAndDirections%28org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType,%20org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction,%20org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType,%20org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction,%20java.lang.Object...%29) with little luck. Tried the way below... Any idea?

```
// The relationships we will follow
RelationshipType isa = DynamicRelationshipType.withName( "is_a" );
RelationshipType partof = DynamicRelationshipType.withName( "part_of" );

Object[] relations = new Object[4];

relations[0] = isa;
relations[1] = Direction.OUTGOING;
relations[2] = partof;
relations[3] = Direction.OUTGOING;

maxdistance = shortestDistance( node1, node2, 1000, relations );
```

...

```
private Integer shortestDistance( Node source, Node target, Integer depth, Object... relations ) {

        PathFinder<org.neo4j.graphdb.Path> finder = GraphAlgoFactory.shortestPath( PathExpanders.forTypesAndDirections( relations ), depth );

...
}
```

Error message:

```
[ERROR] ...:[441,105] method forTypesAndDirections in class org.neo4j.graphdb.PathExpanders cannot be applied to given types;
required: org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType,org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction,org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType,org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction,java.lang.Object[]
found: java.lang.Object[]
reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) STATE exist so that argument type java.lang.Object[] conforms to formal parameter type org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of the method is such that you have to pass the first two pairs in explicitly, then the array if you have more.